# Django: Create an editable form for each instance within a queryset all in one page?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

Sorry if this is too much code, but I believe it is all relevant to the question at hand.

Long story short, on my series_detail page, all episodes belonging to each series is shown, as well as forms to add a new episode or edit an existing one.

The edit episode form, however, requires an instance, which always returns the very first object of the episodes queryset. This is presumably because of the .first(), but I used this since you can only have one object passed as an instance.

What I am trying to achieve is:

- after showing the edit modal next to each episode, show the instance of each episode instead of only the first episode.
- save only that episode's instance after the form is filled
- achieve this without redirecting to an edit page

models.py

```
class Series(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Episode(models.Model):
    series = models.ForeignKey(Series, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    episode_no =  models.IntegerField(null=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=500)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='pics/episodes',)
```

forms.py

```
class EpisodeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField()
    description = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea, required=False)
    episode_no = forms.IntegerField()
    class Meta:
        model = Episode
        fields = ['name', 'description', 'episode_no' ,'image']
```

views.py

```
def series_detail(request, pk):
    try:
        series = Series.objects.get(pk=pk)
    except:
        return render(request, 'error_404.html')
    
    episodes = Episode.objects.filter(series=series).first()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'addepisodeform' in request.POST: 
            e_form = EpisodeForm(request.POST, request.FILES, prefix='addepisode')
            e_form.instance.series = Series.objects.get(pk=pk)
            if e_form.is_valid():
                e_form.save()
                return redirect('series_detail', pk=pk)
                messages.success(request, 'Episode was created')
            else:
                return redirect('series_detail', pk=pk)
                messages.error(request, 'Episode was not created')

        elif 'editepisodeform' in request.POST:
            edit_e_form = EpisodeForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=episodes, prefix='editepisode')
            edit_e_form.instance.series = Series.objects.get(pk=pk)
            if edit_e_form.is_valid():
                edit_e_form.save()
                return redirect('series_detail', pk=pk)
                messages.success(request, 'Episode was updated')
            else:
                return redirect('series_detail', pk=pk)
                messages.error(request, 'Episode was not updated')


    else:
        e_form = EpisodeForm(prefix='addepisode')
        edit_e_form = EpisodeForm(instance=episodes, prefix='editepisode')

    context = {
        'episodes': episodes,
        'e_form': e_form,
        'edit_e_form': edit_e_form

    }
    return render(request, 'series/series_detail.html', context)

def delete_episode(request, pk1, pk2):
    try:
        series = Series.objects.get(pk=pk1)
    except:
        return render(request, 'error_404.html')

    try:
        episode = Episode.objects.get(series=series, episode_no=pk2)
    except:
        return render(request, 'error_404.html')

    episode.delete()
    return redirect('series_detail', pk=pk1)
```

urls.py

```
path('series/<int:pk>/', views.series_detail, name='series_detail'),
path('series/<int:pk1>/episode/<int:pk2>/delete/', views.delete_episode, name='delete_episode'),
```

series_detail.html

```
<button type="submit" name="addepisodeform">
Add Episode
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ e_form }}
</form>
</button>

{% for episode in episodes %}
    {{ episode.name }}
    {{ episode.description}}
    <img src="{{ episode.image.url }}" height="125px" width="300px" style="object-fit: cover;">
    
    <button type="submit" name="editepisodeform">
    Edit Episode
    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ edit_e_form }}
    </form>
    </button>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This is what *formsets* are for: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/formsets/

Comment: I was thinking about doing that, but wasn't sure if it applied to my situation. Would this be achievable within the same page and view?

Comment: Sorry for inquiring so much, but do you think you could show me how I'd go about doing this? I think formsets are used for adding or editing multiple objects at the same time, but how would you retrieve the instance of each episode then? Would I need to link to an edit page because I want to avoid that approach completely? Instead, each edit episode form should be saved in the series_detail page on submit. Thanks for the quick reply and taking the time to answer a potentially noob-ish question.

Comment: Never mind, I got it working. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so it turns out that formsets were the way to go after all. Thanks to Willem Van Onsem's answer, I decided to go that route after all and it worked like a charm.

A form can only edit one instance, but with formsets, I was able to not only edit each episode rather than just the first instance, but even create a new object and delete multiple objects at the same time!

views.py

```
#import the formset
from django.forms import modelformset_factory, inlineformset_factory

#formset
EpisodeFormset = inlineformset_factory(Series, Episode, fields=('name', 'episode_no', 'description', 'image'), can_delete=True, extra=1)

#post call
if request.method == 'POST':
    if 'editepisodeform' in request.POST:
        formset = EpisodeFormset(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=series, prefix='editepisode')
        if formset.is_valid():
            formset.save()
            return redirect('series_detail', pk=pk)
        else:
            return redirect('series_detail', pk=pk)
else:
    formset = EpisodeFormset(instance=series)
```

series_detail.html

```
<div>
    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ formset.management_form }}
        {% for form in formset %}
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="editepisodeform">Edit</button>
            {{ form.as_p }}
            {% for episode in episodes %}
                {% if episode.episode_no == form.episode_no.value %}
                    Episode: {{ episode.episode_no }} <br>
                    Name: {{ episode.name }} <br>
                    <img src="{{ episode.image.url }}" height="125px" width="300px" style="object-fit: cover;"> <br>                      {% endif %}
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
      {% endfor %}
    </form>
</div>
```